# Bash scripting: 365-024=345?

Tags: bash-scripting

I am trying to build some beginner scripts with bash. I want to find how many days left from today until the end of the year, using date program.

So I am using a variable, **current_date=$(date +%j)** to get the number of the day we have now.

If I  **echo** **$current_date** I am getting a result of **024**, as normally expected because we have 24th of January.

So **365-024** are the days left. And here comes my query. Doing the calculation, lets say **calc 365-024** I am getting the value of **345, instead of 341**.

What's wrong? It has something to do with the zero on the front (**0**24) isn't it?

Comment: You can force decimal evaluation in bash by prefixing with `10#` e.g. `$((365-10#$current_date))`. For further discussion, see this [so] question [Bash script, Illegal number: 08](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878218/bash-script-illegal-number-08)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What's wrong? It has something to do with the zero on the front (024) doesn't it?

Yes, it does. The leading `0` means that the number is interpreted as an [Octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base 8) number.

- Octal 024 == Decimal 20.

To interpret the number as a decimal number use:

```
$ echo $((024))
20
```

For more information see  [how to suppress bash octal number interpretation? (to be interpreted as decimal)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70966/how-to-suppress-bash-octal-number-interpretation-to-be-interpreted-as-decimal) which specifically addresses this very issue when performing calculations with `date`.

---

#### Numerical Constants

> A shell script interprets a number as decimal (base 10), unless that number has a special prefix or notation.
>
> - A number preceded by a 0 is octal (base 8).
> - A number preceded by 0x is hexadecimal (base 16).
> - A number with an embedded # evaluates as BASE#NUMBER (with range and notational restrictions).
>
> **Representation of numerical constants**

```
#!/bin/bash
# numbers.sh: Representation of numbers in different bases.

# Decimal: the default
let "dec = 32"
echo "decimal number = $dec"             # 32
# Nothing out of the ordinary here.


# Octal: numbers preceded by '0' (zero)
let "oct = 032"
echo "octal number = $oct"               # 26
# Expresses result in decimal.
# --------- ------ -- -------


# Hexadecimal: numbers preceded by '0x' or '0X'
let "hex = 0x32"
echo "hexadecimal number = $hex"         # 50

echo $((0x9abc))                         # 39612
#     ^^      ^^   double-parentheses arithmetic expansion/evaluation
# Expresses result in decimal.



# Other bases: BASE#NUMBER
# BASE between 2 and 64.
# NUMBER must use symbols within the BASE range, see below.


let "bin = 2#111100111001101"
echo "binary number = $bin"              # 31181

let "b32 = 32#77"
echo "base-32 number = $b32"             # 231

let "b64 = 64#@_"
echo "base-64 number = $b64"             # 4031
# This notation only works for a limited range (2 - 64) of ASCII characters.
# 10 digits + 26 lowercase characters + 26 uppercase characters + @ + _


echo

echo $((36#zz)) $((2#10101010)) $((16#AF16)) $((53#1aA))
                                         # 1295 170 44822 3375


#  Important note:
#  --------------
#  Using a digit out of range of the specified base notation
#+ gives an error message.

let "bad_oct = 081"
# (Partial) error message output:
#  bad_oct = 081: value too great for base (error token is "081")
#              Octal numbers use only digits in the range 0 - 7.

exit $?   # Exit value = 1 (error)

# Thanks, Rich Bartell and Stephane Chazelas, for clarification.
```

Source [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide - Numerical Constants](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/numerical-constants.html)

Answer (score 1):

Writing numbers with leading 0 is a convention for octal notation, just like prefixing with 0x is for hexadecimal. So 024 is interpreted like 2*8+4 == 20. See output of the command:

```
echo $(( 024 ))
```

Strip leading zeroes using code examples from @steeldriver's code in comment below.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to resort to `sed` here: either use date format `%-j` to eliminate the zero-padding at source, use an explicit base in the shell `10#$current_date`, or remove the leading zero using parameter substitution `${current_date#0}`